# Allow access between Azure Web App and Azure PostgreSQL without opening all public/Azure IPs

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

**Problem**:

Use an ARM template to create an Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server and a Web App (for NodeJS backend), then allow the Web App to talk to the PostgreSQL DB. Additionally, developers and admins shall have access to the DB via DB client (pgAdmin) from the public network.

**General solution options found so far**:

1. Allow all public IPs in the range 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 (no option due to security concerns)
2. Allow all Azure IPs (for the Web App to have access) and additional single IPs for pgAdmin clients (no option due to security concerns because no knowledge/control over other parties' Azure resources having access to the DB)
3. Private access: Create a virtual network and put PostgreSQL DB and Web App in there, then also create a virtual machine within that virtual network so that chosen public users can connect with their pgAdmin client to the DB through the VM (less desired option since the VM will only serve as a gateway to the vet but will cost money and may not be used regularly enough to justify the cost)

**Question:**

Is there a way to programmatically (via the ARM template) whitelist only the possible IPs of the Web App (so that I don't have to use a vNet)? Or are there any other ways (apart from IP whitelisting and private access) to make the Web App have access to the DB? Whitelisting single IPs for pgAdmin users is not a problem (either via ARM template parameter or manually after PostgreSQL resource creation).

Thanks a lot and cheers

Stefan

Comment: Azure has on-demand firewall rules for Azure SQL, don't they have the same thing for Postgres? Also, if you're so concerned about security, don't you have per-user logins with fine-grained permissions set-up? Are you using AAD? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/concepts-azure-ad-authentication

Comment: You can directly use variables and allow your web app Ip's in your Postgresql via ARM template - },
  "variables": {
    "firewallrules": [
      {
        "Name": "rule1",
        "StartIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "EndIpAddress": "255.255.255.255"
      },
      {
        "Name": "rule2",
        "StartIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "EndIpAddress": "255.255.255.255"
      }
    ]
  }, Refer complete ARM template here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/quickstart-create-postgresql-server-database-using-arm-template?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SiddheshDesai, but if I understand correctly this would require knowledge of the web app's IPs before ARM template deployment (so that I can specify them in the template) or, as in the documentation link provided, use the full IP range (which is undesired as stated above). Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @StefanKlocke You cannot define firewall rules within Azure that are specific to Azure App Services - [it's all-or-nothing with the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-firewall-rules) _"Allow public access from any Azure service within Azure to this server"_ option. Also, the public IP addresses of Azure App Services will not be the addresses used to connect to the Postgres instance, so Siddhesh's suggestion won't work anyway.

Comment: Just add the specific Inbound and Outbound Ips of your web app as referred here-https://i.imgur.com/ksevsfg.png in  your postgresql firewall rules

Comment: I would use VNet integration (as in your solution 3) but instead of VM would use VPN Gateway for access to VNet.
Another option is to set up [static outbound IP for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-outbound-ip), but I think that VNet+VPN is still better security-wise.